# Class not found PHP (2FA package)

Tags: php

I'm using this package: https://github.com/RobThree/TwoFactorAuth and I'm trying to follow the part of the guide where you can use your own QR code provider.

I downloaded the `phpqrcode.php` file and placed it in the directory where `TwoFactorAuth.php` is located.

When `require_once` is at the top like in the guide, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in /var/www/public/vendor/robthree/twofactorauth/lib/Providers/Qr/MyProvider.php on line 4

So, in the directory with `TwoFactorAuth.php` I added `myprovider.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
namespace RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../phpqrcode.php');

class MyProvider implements IQRCodeProvider {
  public function getMimeType() {
    return 'image/png';                             // This provider only returns PNG's
  }

  public function getQRCodeImage($qrtext, $size) {
    ob_start();                                     // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    QRCode::png($qrtext, null, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3, 4); // We ignore $size and set it to 3
                                                    // since phpqrcode doesn't support
                                                    // a size in pixels...
    $result = ob_get_contents();                    // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    ob_end_clean();                                 // Cleanup
    return $result;                                 // Return image
  }
}
```

I then use the following code to attempt to generate a QR code, similarly to the readme:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mp = new RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr\MyProvider();
$tfa = new RobThree\Auth\TwoFactorAuth('My Company', 6, 30, 'sha1', $mp);
$secret = $tfa->createSecret();
echo $tfa->getQRCodeImageAsDataUri('Bob Ross', $secret);
?>
```

But then I get this error..

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr\QRCode' not found in /var/www/public/vendor/robthree/twofactorauth/lib/Providers/Qr/MyProvider.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/public/vendor/robthree/twofactorauth/lib/TwoFactorAuth.php(146): RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr\MyProvider->getQRCodeImage('otpauth://totp/...', 200) #1 /var/www/public/test.php(6): RobThree\Auth\TwoFactorAuth->getQRCodeImageAsDataUri('Bob Ross', 'ID2Y3P5C6N2NXKD...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/public/vendor/robthree/twofactorauth/lib/Providers/Qr/MyProvider.php on line 13

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the class `Qr` either via it's fully resolved namespace, otr through a `use` statement.  Adding `namespace RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr;` to the top of your code places your code inside the namespace of that library, which is an extremely bad design pattern.  Not only is your code not part of the RobThree Auth library, but what happens when you need to use another library?

Try using this code instead, it is the proper design and you won't run into problems.  Also, I would suggest namespacing your own classes, under something like `MyOrganisation\MyLibrary`, which I have included below:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../phpqrcode.php');

namespace MyOrganisation\MyLibrary;

use RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr\QRCode;

class MyProvider implements IQRCodeProvider {
  public function getMimeType() {
    return 'image/png';                             // This provider only returns PNG's
  }

  public function getQRCodeImage($qrtext, $size) {
    ob_start();                                     // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    QRCode::png($qrtext, null, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3, 4); // We ignore $size and set it to 3
                                                    // since phpqrcode doesn't support
                                                    // a size in pixels...
    $result = ob_get_contents();                    // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    ob_end_clean();                                 // Cleanup
    return $result;                                 // Return image
  }
}
```

The other option to this code (which I mentioned initially) would be:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../phpqrcode.php');

namespace MyOrganisation\MyLibrary;

class MyProvider implements IQRCodeProvider {
  public function getMimeType() {
    return 'image/png';                             // This provider only returns PNG's
  }

  public function getQRCodeImage($qrtext, $size) {
    ob_start();                                     // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr\QRCode::png($qrtext, null, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3, 4); // We ignore $size and set it to 3
                                                    // since phpqrcode doesn't support
                                                    // a size in pixels...
    $result = ob_get_contents();                    // 'Catch' QRCode's output
    ob_end_clean();                                 // Cleanup
    return $result;                                 // Return image
  }
}
```

The first solution leads to much neater code, especially with deeply nested namespaced classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the tutorial, you can use the following code

```
\QRCode::png($qrtext, null, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Please explain in your answer how this differs from what the Asker has and how that difference is important to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `namespace RobThree\Auth\Providers\Qr;` to the top of `phpqrcode.php`